# NullPointerException when reading a json file inside a jar file

Tags: java, inputstream, fileinputstream

I am trying to run a class inside a jar file. Inside the java program, I have a class called `CustomSearchHandler` which is calling a function to read an array of strings from a JSON file called `Attributes.json`. Note that this JSON file is in the same directory as the class.

```
public class CustomSearchHandler extends SearchHandler {
    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomSearchHandler.class);

    public static final String CURRENCYCODEHEADER = "currencycode";

    @Override
    public void handleRequestBody(SolrQueryRequest solrRequest,
                                  SolrQueryResponse solrResponse) throws Exception {
          ArrayList<String> fixedAttributesList = fetchAttributes("fixed_attributes");

    }
  
    public static ArrayList<String> fetchAttributes(String type){
        ArrayList<String> attributesList = new ArrayList<String>();
        try{
            InputStream inputStream = CustomSearchHandler.class.getResourceAsStream("Attributes.json");
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            JSONArray jsonArray = json.getJSONArray("fixed_attributes");
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                attributesList.add(jsonArray.getString(i));
            }
            logger.info("e");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return attributesList;
    }
}
```

When I create a jar from this and execute this, I get -

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.base/java.io.Reader.<init>(Reader.java:167)
        at java.base/java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(InputStreamReader.java:72)
        at CustomSearchHandler.fetchAttributes(CustomSearchHandler.java:125)
        at CustomSearchHandler.handleRequestBody(CustomSearchHandler.java:60)
```

I just need to read the list of strings of array "fixed_attributes" and assign it to an ArrayList. Please help.

Comment: _Note that this json file is in the same directory as the class._ No, it's not. Hence the null pointer exception. You can run `System.out.println(CustomSearchHandler.class.getResource("CustomSearchHandler.class"))` to see where it's looking.

Comment: I also logged the result of file.exists() method, and it shows the file is not present. But it is in the same directory.

Comment: Yes but there are different ways of loading files: either from the filesystem or from the classpath. It could be in the same folder and the path could look right but if you're loading from the classpath and the classpath definition doesn't include that file or that type of file then you are toast.

Comment: *"I also logged the result of file.exists() method, and it shows the file is not present. But it is in the same directory."* - an "embedded resource" mostly likely won't exist on the file disk (and based on your own description, should be inside the jar file) - so using `File#exists` is pointless.  You should, first, unzip the jar file (yes, it's just a zip file) and check that the file you're trying to load has actually been packed into (at the same location as the class trying to load it)

Comment: @sidharth you need to run the snippet in my comment and tell us what it prints / with that output you can probably figure it out yourself.

Comment: @MadProgrammer I couldn't find the json file anywhere when I unzipped it.

Comment: So, here’s the million dollar question- are expecting the json file to be bundled with your jar or loaded off the disk at runtime?

Comment: resources should be in resource directory.

Another way,  you can try, but I'm not sure about it, you can get link to your resource by
ClassPathResource(String path, @Nullable Class<?> clazz)

Create a new ClassPathResource for Class usage. The path can be relative to the given class, or absolute within the classpath via a leading slash.
Params:
path – relative or absolute path within the class path
clazz – the class to load resources with